# Convexity of $\ln \det(\mbox{diag}(x)^{-1} + A)$ with $A$ given and positive definite.

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, determinant, positive-definite

> Show that $$f(x) = \ln \det \left( \mbox{diag}(x)^{-1} + A \right)$$ is convex when $x \in \mathbb R^n_{++}$ and $A$ is given and positive definite.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What's $\mathbb{R}_{++}^n$?

Comment: Interesting question. Two easy special cases are when $x$ is a scalar, not a vector, and when $A$ is diagonal, as then one can easily write out the eigenvalues in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $x$ to get a sum of convex functions in $x$. I'm not sure how to express the eigenvalues when $A$ is generic and $x$ is a vector. The Hessian of $\ln \det$ is known, but is a little complicated so might not help...

Comment: $\mathbb R^n_{++}$ means the set of element-wise all positive  $n$-vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use that the function
$$
X \mapsto \log\det( I + X^{-1})$$
is convex on symmetric, positive definite $X$, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0611043).

Indeed,
$$
\log\det( x^{-1} + A)
= \log\det( A^{-1} \, x^{-1} + I) + \log\det(A)
= \log\det( (x \, A)^{-1} + I) + \log\det(A),
$$
where $x^{-1}$ short for $\operatorname{diag}(x)^{-1}$.